# Redux-Thunk: Concurrent requests

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have two actions:

```
getChats(){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState().chats;
        if(state.isLoading || state.isRequested) {
            console.log('CHATS_REQUESTING_BUSY');
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        console.log('CHATS_REQUESTING');
        dispatch(chats_loading);
        return fetch().then(response => {
            console.log('CHATS_REQUESTED');
            return dispatch(chats_loaded)
        });
    };
}

getChat(id){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(this.getChats)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('CHAT_REQUESTED');
                let chat = selectChat(getState(), id); // selector
                // some additional logic here
            });
    };
}
```

Let's pretend that I have a situation, when this two requests called parallel.
Something like:

```
store.dispatch(this.ChatsActions.getChats);
store.dispatch(this.ChatsActions.getChat(12345));
```

And I'm getting this:

```
'CHATS_REQUESTING'
'CHATS_REQUESTING_BUSY'
'CHAT_REQUESTED'
'CHATS_REQUESTED'
```

In second call `getChat` doesn't wait getChats `dispatch`. Is it right behaviour or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Actually I'm using angularJS (ng-redux), but I guess it's not important.

Comment: it is waiting for the initial dispatch but you break early with a resolved promise (_due to loading state from first request_) so you get the `CHAT_REQUESTED`

Comment: Yeah, already figured this. I guess I should store initial request promise and return it instead of resolved promise. Thx.